# Unable to iterate the slab fields

Tags: jquery

If I click on "add slab" the fields will appear and I am going to enter wrong values it should show validations, yes its coming properly.
If I click "add slab" once again and entered wrong values it's not showing the validation second time. Iteration is not happening, please help me.

```
function validatecommissionpercent() {
    var commReg = "^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$";
    var status = true;

    var commissionpercentval = jQuery('#commissionpercentId').val();
    var commissionminamountval = jQuery('#commissionamountId').val();

    if (jQuery("#commissionpercentId").val().match(commReg)) {

        jQuery("#commissionpercentErrMsg").hide();
    } else {

        jQuery("#commissionpercentErrMsg").text("Invalid entry ");
        jQuery("#commissionpercentErrMsg").show();
        status = false;
    }

    if (jQuery("#commissionamountId").val().match(commReg)) {

        jQuery("#commissionminamountErrMsg").hide();
    } else {

        jQuery("#commissionminamountErrMsg").text("Invalid entry ");
        jQuery("#commissionminamountErrMsg").show();
        status = false;
    }
    if (commissionpercentval < 0) {

        jQuery("#commissionpercentErrMsg").text("-ve values are not allowed ");
        jQuery('#commissionpercentErrMsg').show();
        status = false;

    } else if (status == true) {
        jQuery('#commissionpercentErrMsg').hide();
    }

    if (commissionminamountval < 0) {

        jQuery("#commissionminamountErrMsg").text("-ve values are not allowed ");
        jQuery('#commissionminamountErrMsg').show();
        status = false;

    } else if (status == true) {
        jQuery('#commissionminamountErrMsg').hide();
    }


    var commissionpercent1 = jQuery('#commissionpercentId').val();
    var commissionminamount1 = jQuery('#commissionamountId').val();



    var commisionDataArray = commissionpercent1.split(".");
    var commissionAmountArray = commissionminamount1.split(".");



    var prefixNum = commisionDataArray[0];
    var suffixNum = commisionDataArray[1];



    var prefixAmountNum = commissionAmountArray[0];
    var suffixAmountNum = commissionAmountArray[1];



    if (prefixNum != null || prefixAmountNum != null) {


        if (suffixNum != '' && suffixNum != null && suffixNum.length > 2) {

            jQuery('#commissionpercentErrMsg').text("should accept only 2 decimal values");
            jQuery('#commissionpercentErrMsg').show();
            status = false;

        }
        if (suffixAmountNum != '' && suffixAmountNum != null && suffixAmountNum.length > 2) {

            jQuery('#commissionminamountErrMsg').text("should accept only 2 decimal values");
            jQuery('#commissionminamountErrMsg').show();
            status = false;
        }


    } else {
        if (suffixNum.length <= 2) {
            if (status == true || status == 'true') {

                jQuery('#commissionpercentErrMsg').text("");
                jQuery('#commissionpercentErrMsg').hide();
            }

        }
        if (suffixAmountNum.length <= 2) {

            if (status == true || status == 'true') {

                jQuery('#commissionminamountErrMsg').text("");
                jQuery('#commissionminamountErrMsg').hide();
            }

        }
    }

    return status;
}

function validateslabflag() {
    var commReg = "^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$";
    var status = true;

    var startingamountval = jQuery('#saId').val();
    var endamounttval = jQuery('#eaId').val();
    var fixedamountval = jQuery('#faId').val();
    var percentageval = jQuery('#pId').val();
    var maximumamountval = jQuery('#maId').val();

    if (jQuery("#saId").val().match(commReg)) {
        if (status == true) {
            jQuery("#saErrMsg").hide();
        }
    } else {

        jQuery("#saErrMsg").text("Invalid entry ");
        jQuery("#saErrMsg").show();
        status = false;
    }
    if (jQuery("#eaId").val().match(commReg)) {
        if (status == true) {
            jQuery("#eaErrMsg").hide();
        }
    } else {

        jQuery("#eaErrMsg").text("Invalid entry ");
        jQuery("#eaErrMsg").show();
        status = false;
    }
    if (jQuery("#faId").val().match(commReg)) {
        if (status == true) {
            jQuery("#faErrMsg").hide();
        }
    } else {

        jQuery("#faErrMsg").text("Invalid entry ");
        jQuery("#faErrMsg").show();
        status = false;
    }
    if (jQuery("#pId").val().match(commReg)) {
        if (status == true) {
            jQuery("#pErrMsg").hide();
        }
    } else {

        jQuery("#pErrMsg").text("Invalid entry ");
        jQuery("#pErrMsg").show();
        status = false;
    }
    if (jQuery("#maId").val().match(commReg)) {
        if (status == true) {
            jQuery("#maErrMsg").hide();
        }
    } else {

        jQuery("#maErrMsg").text("Invalid entry ");
        jQuery("#maErrMsg").show();
        status = false;
    }

    if (startingamountval < 0) {

        jQuery("#saErrMsg").text("-ve values are not allowed ");
        jQuery('#saErrMsg').show();
        status = false;

    } else if (status == true) {
        jQuery('#saErrMsg').hide();
    }

    if (endamounttval < 0) {

        jQuery("#eaErrMsg").text("-ve values are not allowed ");
        jQuery('#eaErrMsg').show();
        status = false;

    } else if (status == true) {
        jQuery('#eaErrMsg').hide();
    }
    if (fixedamountval < 0) {

        jQuery("#faErrMsg").text("-ve values are not allowed ");
        jQuery('#faErrMsg').show();
        status = false;

    } else if (status == true) {
        jQuery('#faErrMsg').hide();
    }
    if (percentageval < 0) {

        jQuery("#pErrMsg").text("-ve values are not allowed ");
        jQuery('#pErrMsg').show();
        status = false;

    } else if (status == true) {
        jQuery('#pErrMsg').hide();
    }
    if (maximumamountval < 0) {

        jQuery("#maErrMsg").text("-ve values are not allowed ");
        jQuery('#maErrMsg').show();
        status = false;

    } else if (status == true) {
        jQuery('#maErrMsg').hide();
    }
    var saval1 = jQuery('#saId').val();
    var eaval1 = jQuery('#eaId').val();
    var faval1 = jQuery('#faId').val();
    var pval1 = jQuery('#pId').val();
    var maval1 = jQuery('#maId').val();

    saDataArray = saval1.split(".");
    eaDataArray = eaval1.split(".");
    faDataArray = faval1.split(".");
    pDataArray = pval1.split(".");
    maDataArray = maval1.split(".");

    var pn1 = saDataArray[0];
    var sn1 = saDataArray[1];

    var pn2 = eaDataArray[0];
    var sn2 = eaDataArray[1];

    var pn3 = faDataArray[0];
    var sn3 = faDataArray[1];

    var pn4 = pDataArray[0];
    var sn4 = pDataArray[1];

    var pn5 = maDataArray[0];
    var sn5 = maDataArray[1];


    if (pn1 != null || pn2 != null) {
        if (sn1 != '' && sn1 != null && sn1.length > 2)

        {

            jQuery('#saErrMsg').text("should accept only 2 decimal values");
            jQuery('#saErrMsg').show();
            status = false;

        }
        if (sn2 != '' && sn2 != null && sn2.length > 2) {
            jQuery('#eaErrMsg').text("should accept only 2 decimal values");
            jQuery('#eaErrMsg').show();
            status = false;
        }
    } else {
        if (sn1.length <= 2) {
            if (status == true || status == 'true') {
                jQuery('#saErrMsg').text("");
                jQuery('#saErrMsg').hide();
            }
        }
        if (sn2.length <= 2) {
            if (status == true || status == 'true') {
                jQuery('#eaErrMsg').text("");
                jQuery('#eaErrMsg').hide();

            }
        }
    }
    if (pn3 != null || pn4 != null) {
        if (sn3 != '' && sn3 != null && sn3.length > 2)

        {

            jQuery('#faErrMsg').text("should accept only 2 decimal values");
            jQuery('#faErrMsg').show();
            status = false;

        }
        if (sn4 != '' && sn4 != null && sn4.length > 2) {
            jQuery('#pErrMsg').text("should accept only 2 decimal values");
            jQuery('#pErrMsg').show();
            status = false;
        }
    } else {
        if (sn3.length <= 2) {
            if (status == true || status == 'true') {
                jQuery('#faErrMsg').text("");
                jQuery('#faErrMsg').hide();
            }
        }
        if (sn4.length <= 2) {
            if (status == true || status == 'true') {
                jQuery('#pErrMsg').text("");
                jQuery('#pErrMsg').hide();

            }
        }
    }
    if (pn5 != null) {
        if (sn5 != '' && sn5 != null && sn5.length > 2)

        {

            jQuery('#maErrMsg').text("should accept only 2 decimal values");
            jQuery('#maErrMsg').show();
            status = false;

        }

    } else {
        if (sn5.length <= 2) {
            if (status == true || status == 'true') {
                jQuery('#maErrMsg').text("");
                jQuery('#maErrMsg').hide();
            }
        }

    }
    return status;

}
```

Comment: Please post a plunk or a fiddle.

Comment: sir dis not get you..what should i provide?

Comment: Take your code, and put it into this - jsfiddle.net - and it will be easier for people to help you.